# No current through the motor when using opto couplers to drive the mosfets in the H-bridge

Tags: h-bridge

I'm using opto-couplers 4N35 as a driver for an H-bridge. But there seems to be no current flowing through and the voltage is all over the place. The PWM is 3.3 V, 5 kHz (The circuit diagram has it as 500 however)

[image: PWM and driver]

This the driver circuit and the H-bridge. I am using 4 n-chanel MOSFETs (IRFZ44)

[image: H-Bridge]

The output from the motor is as follows:

[image: Motor voltage]

[image: Motor current]

Comment: Look up "source follower".

Answer (score 1):

**Advice about your faulty H-bridge design:**

Your upper power supply rail is **9 volts** and, if you want the **upper** N channel MOSFETs to activate properly, the source voltage should "pull" to "near-enough" 9 volts **BUT**, because an N channel MOSFET needs the gate voltage to be significantly higher than the source voltage (when activated), the driver circuit for the upper MOSFETs has to run from a supply that is maybe **14 volts** to **25 volts**.

Currently, your H-bridge drivers can only, at best, connect the gate to 9 volts and that means the source cannot be effectively pulled to anywhere near the 9 volt supply line (with a decent load connected to the output). The lower MOSFETs are fine because they are wired as common-source.

> *No current through the motor when using opto couplers to drive the
> mosfets in the H-bridge*

Try a resistive load in case your motor model is somehow faulty.

Comment: On top of what Andy said, you can cheat your way around this with a photovoltaic optocoupler, for example VOM1271. It will however need very low gate capacitance at 5 kHz as the drive is very weak. Consider a real gate driver instead such as IR2113.